# Bundle external javascript libraries automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bundle, npm-install

I often see browser-focused javascript libraries with an option to install over `npm`.

Is there a reason to install it using npm instead of just using `<script src="cdn-url"></script>`?

I am loading many libraries, so I guess it might be a good idea to fetch these files, so I don't make so many url requests (even though all the requests are targeting CDNs).

I could potentially install via npm and then use `<script src='/node_modules/...'></script>`, but then I need to make these paths public accessible using `express.static()` or something like that.

I know that I could use webpack, browserify, etc., but they seem overly complicated when I just want to bundle a few external libraries into 1 file automatically.

Comment: not too sure what do u mean by they are overly complicated. js/css file bundling is done together with babelify.

Answer (score 0):

The point of using npm in this case is so you get the updates automatically. You bundle to reduce the number of requests and include only 1 script tag.

> but they seem overly complicated when I just want to bundle a few external libraries into 1 file automatically.

This is complicated unfortunately. It would be nice if it wasn't. Also, you need to think about things like browser caching when you update a library. If you have a vendor libraries bundle, you will have to manually cachebust with a query string when you update. So to simplify the process, webpack does it all for you.

I would move to Webpack and use the CommonsChunkPlugin to create a vendor build. [See this example.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points-commons-chunk-css-bundle#webpackconfigjs)

To fully automate everything, combine this with [Html Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) to automatically add the script tags and cache-bust with hashing.